# Second Order Differential Equation: $y’’+y’= t^3,$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using undetermined coefficients for this second order differential equation.  For $y’’+y’= t^3,$ how come my $y_p$ is raised to the $4^{th}$ power instead of just $y_p(t)= At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D?$ Why does $y_p(t)$ need to be $At^4?$

Comment: Is your independent variable $p, t,$ or $x?$

Comment: Sorry, all of them should be t

Comment: since this is linear ODE you might want to use the method of variation of parameters. 
Also try substituting your solution without the term $t^{4}$ and you will see why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $y_p$ you need a solution to satisfy your equation $$y''+y' = t^3$$

If you notice under  first and second  differentiation  the degree of a third degree polynomial will reduce to two and one, so you need $t^4$ so after first and second differentiation  you get a third degree polynomial such as $t^3$ on the right hand side of your equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate once you find that
$$
y'+y=\frac{t^4}4+K.
$$
Now that left and right side no longer share an exponent, you can find the particular solution in the form
$$
y_p=At^4+Bt^3+Ct^2+Dt+K.
$$
Note that the constant $K$ is part of the homogeneous solution of the original equation.

---

In general, if the right side is a sum of terms $p(t)e^{rt}$, and if $m$ is the multiplicity of $r$ in the characteristic polynomial of the left side, then the trial solution for each one of the right side terms is $t^mq(t)e^{rt}$, where $\deg q=\deg p$ and the coefficients of $q$ are the unknown variables. The complete particular solution is the sum of all these terms.

Here you have $r=0$ and $m=1$, so that
$$
y_p=t(At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D)e^{0\cdot t}
$$